# Updated stages variable to which is working

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

**UPDATE**
i got the variable working which passes the terraform plan flying colors.  That said when i run terraform apply I get a new error:

> creating CodePipeline (dev-mgt-mytest-cp): ValidationException: 2
> validation errors detected: Value at
> 'pipeline.stages.1.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to
> satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must
> have length less than or equal to 50000, Member must have length
> greater than or equal to 1]; Value at
> 'pipeline.stages.2.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to
> satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must
> have length less than or equal to 50000, Member must have a length
> greater than or equal to 1]

I don't believe this is a limit for the code pipeline since I have done this pipeline manually without dynamic stages, and it works fine.  Not sure if this is a terraform hard limit.  Looking for some help here.  Also, I have updated the code with the working variable for those looking for the syntax.

**OLD POST**

================================================================

I am giving my first stab at creating dynamic stages and really struggling with the documentation out there.  What I have put together so far is based on articles found here in StackOverflow and a few resources online.  So far I think i have good syntax, but the value i am passing is from my main.tf is getting an error:

> The given value is not suitable for the module.test_code.var.stages
> declared at │ ../dynamic_pipeline/variables.tf:60,1-18: all list
> elements must have the same │ type.

### Part 1

All I am trying to do basically is pass in dynamic stages into the pipeline. Once I get the stages working, I will add the new dynamic variables.  I am providing the dynamic module, variables.tf for the module, and then my test run along with variables.

**dynamic_pipeline.tf**

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "cp_plan_pipeline" {
  name        = "${local.cp_name}-cp"
  role_arn    = var.cp_run_role

  artifact_store {
    type      = var.cp_artifact_type
    location  = var.cp_artifact_bucketname

  }

  dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = [for s in var.stages : {
      name   = s.name
      action = s.action
    } if(lookup(s, "enabled", true))]

    content {
      name = stage.value.name
      dynamic "action" {
        for_each = stage.value.action
        content {
          name             = action.value["name"]
          owner            = action.value["owner"]
          version          = action.value["version"]
          category         = action.value["category"]
          provider         = action.value["provider"]
          run_order        = lookup(action.value, "run_order", null)
          namespace        = lookup(action.value, "namespace", null)
          region           = lookup(action.value, "region", data.aws_region.current.name)
          input_artifacts  = lookup(action.value, "input_artifacts", [])
          output_artifacts = lookup(action.value, "output_artifacts", [])
          configuration    = {
            RepositoryName        = lookup(action.value, "repository_name", null)
            ProjectName           = lookup(action.value, "ProjectName", null)
            BranchName            = lookup(action.value, "branch_name", null)
            PollForSourceChanges  = lookup(action.value, "poll_for_sourcechanges", null)
            OutputArtifactFormat  = lookup(action.value, "ouput_format", null)
          }
          
        }
      }
    }
  }


}
```

**variables.tf**

```
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # General
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        variable "region" {
          type        = string
          description = "The AWS Region to be used when deploying region-specific resources (Default: us-east-1)"
          default     = "us-east-1"
        }
        
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # CODEPIPELINE VARIABLES
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        variable "cp_name" {
          type        = string
          description = "The name of the codepipline"
        }
        
        variable "cp_repo_name" {
          type        = string
          description = "Then name of the repo that will be used as a source repo to trigger builds"
        }
        
        variable "cp_branch_name" {
          type        = string
          description = "The branch of the repo that will be watched and used to trigger deployment"
          default     = "development"
        }
        
        variable "cp_artifact_bucketname" {
          type        = string
          description = "name of the artifact bucket where articacts are stored."
          default     = "Codepipeline-artifacts-s3"
        }
        
        variable "cp_run_role" {
          type        = string
          description = "S3 artifact bucket name."
          
        }
        
        variable "cp_artifact_type" {
          type        = string
          description = ""
          default     = "S3"
        }
        
        variable "cp_poll_sources" {
          description = "Trigger that lets codepipeline know that it needs to trigger build on change"
          type        = bool
          default     = false
        }
        
        variable "cp_ouput_format" {
          type        = string
          description = "Output artifacts format that is used to save the outputs"
          default = "CODE_ZIP"
        }
        
variable "stages" {
  type        = list(object({
    name      = string
    action    = list(object({
      name              = string
      owner             = string
      version           = string
      category          = string
      provider          = string
      run_order         = number
      namespace         = string
      region            = string
      input_artifacts   = list(string)
      output_artifacts  = list(string)
      repository_name   = string
      ProjectName       = string
      branch_name             = string
      poll_for_sourcechanges  = bool
      output_format           = string

    }))
  }))
  
  description = "This list describes each stage of the build"

}
        
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # ENVIORNMENT VARIABLES
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        variable "env" {
          type        = string
          description = "The environment to deploy resources (dev | test | prod | sbx)"
          default     = "dev"
        }
        
        variable "tenant" {
          type        = string
          description = "The Service Tenant in which the IaC is being deployed to"
          default     = "dummytenant"
        }
        
        variable "project" {
          type        = string
          description = "The Project Name or Acronym. (Note: You should consider setting this in your Enviornment  Variables.)"
        }
        
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Parameter Store Variables
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        variable "bucketlocation" {
          type        = string
          description = "location within the S3 bucket where the State file resides"
        }
```

### Part 2

That is the main makeup of the pipeline.  Below is the module I created to try to execute as a test to ensure it works.  This is where I am getting the error

**main.tf**

```
module test_code {

    source          = "../dynamic_pipeline"
    cp_name         = "dynamic-actions" 
    project         = "my_project"
    bucketlocation  = var.backend_bucket_target_name
    cp_run_role     = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/cp-deploy-service-role"
    cp_repo_name    = var.repo
    
    stages          = [{  
        name = "part 1"
        action  = [{
            name                    = "Source"
            owner                   = "AWS"
            version                 = "1"
            category                = "Source"
            provider                = "CodeCommit"
            run_order               = 1
            repository_name         = "my_target_repo"
            branch_name             = "main"
            poll_for_sourcechanges  = true
            output_artifacts        = ["CodeWorkspace"]
            ouput_format            = var.cp_ouput_format

        }]
    },
    {
        name = "part 2"
        action  = [{
            run_order               = 1    
            name                    = "Combine_Binaries"
            owner                   = "AWS"
            version                 = "1"
            category                = "Build"
            provider                = "CodeBuild"
            namespace               = "BIN"
            input_artifacts         = ["CodeWorkspace"]
            output_artifacts        = ["CodeSource"]
            ProjectName             = "test_runner"

        }]
    }]


}
```

variables files associated with the run book:

**variables.tf**

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CODEPIPELINE VARIABLES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

variable "cp_branch_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The branch of the repo that will be watched and used to trigger deployment"
  default     = "development"
}

variable "cp_poll_sources" {
  description = "Trigger that lets codepipeline know that it needs to trigger build on change"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "cp_ouput_format" {
  type        = string
  description = "Output artifacts format that is used to save the outputs. Values can be CODEBUILD_CLONE_REF or CODE_ZIP"
  default = "CODE_ZIP"
}

variable "backend_bucket_target_name" {

  type        = string
  description = "The folder name where the state file is stored for the pipeline"
  default     = "dynamic-test-pl"

}

variable "repo" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of the repo the pipeine is managing"
  default = "my_target_repo"
  
}
```

I know this is my first time trying this.  Not very good with Lists and maps on terraform, but I am certain it has to do with the way i am passing it in.  Any help or guidance would be appreciated it.

Comment: Well, terraform complains because the list data type expects all the values to be of the same type: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints. In other words `list(any)` is the same as `list(string)` or `list(number)`. You probably want a `list(object)`.

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: Marko, I am working on changing will update my post with what i have so far.

Comment: You are getting the same error?

Comment: Yup same error after the change.

Comment: That is almost impossible. Can you remove the `.terraform` directory and run `terraform init` again from the directory where the root module is?

Comment: New Error

The given value is not suitable for module.test_code.var.stages declared at ../dynamic_pipeline/variables.tf:60,1-18: map of
│ object required.

Comment: So you have to change the values that you are assigning to the module variable since it's no longer a list but a map.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the variable to list(object and got the following error: The given value is not suitable for module.test_code.var.stages declared at ../dynamic_pipeline/variables.tf:60,1-18: element 0:
│ attribute "action": object required.    so i am playing with that right now.

Comment: So Marko, I have concluded that variables are not possible for dynamic stages.  Several other references have led me to create a YAML file that gets consumed and passed in.  I am working on that now with success and will post once I have a good working example.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I finally found the answer to this issue.  Special thanks to this [thread on github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/14357). It put me in the right direction.  A couple of things to take away from this.  Variable declaration is the essential part of Dynamic Pipeline.  I worked with several working examples that yielded great results for Stages and Actions, but when it came to the configuration environment variables, they all crashed. The root problem that I concluded was that you could not perform Dynamic Actions with Environment variables and hope for terraform to perform the JSON translation for you.  In some cases it would work but required that every Action contain similar elements which led to character constraints and errors like my post called out.

My best guess is that terraform has a hard limit on variables and their character limits.  The solution, declare the resource as a dynamic that seems to support different limits versus traditional variables within a resource.  The approach that was taken makes the entire Terraform Resource a Dynamic attribute which I feel is treated differently by terraform in its entirety with fewer limits (an assumption).  I say that because I tried four methods of dynamic staging and actions.  Those methods worked up until I introduced the environment variables (forces JSON conversion on a specific resource type) and then I would get various errors all pointing at either a variable not supported for missing attributes or a variable that exceeds terraform character limits.

What worked was creating the entire resource as a dynamic resource which I could pass in as a map attribute that includes the EnvironmentVariables.  See examples below.

**Final Dynamic Pipeline**

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  for_each = var.code_pipeline
  name     = "${local.name_prefix}-${var.AppName}"
  role_arn = each.value["code_pipeline_role_arn"]

  tags = {
    Pipeline_Key = each.key
  }

  artifact_store {
    type     = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? "" : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "type", "S3")
    location = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? null : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "artifact_bucket", null)
  }

  dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "stages", {})
    iterator = stage
    content {
      name = lookup(stage.value, "name")
      dynamic "action" {
        for_each = lookup(stage.value, "actions", {}) //[stage.key]
        iterator = action
        content {
          name             = action.value["name"]
          category         = action.value["category"]
          owner            = action.value["owner"]
          provider         = action.value["provider"]
          version          = action.value["version"]
          run_order        = action.value["run_order"]
          input_artifacts  = lookup(action.value, "input_artifacts", null)
          output_artifacts = lookup(action.value, "output_artifacts", null)
          configuration    = action.value["configuration"]
          namespace        = lookup(action.value, "namespace", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Calling Dynamic Pipeline**

```
module "code_pipeline" {
  source = "../module-aws-codepipeline" #using module locally
  #source       = "your-github-repository/aws-codepipeline" #using github repository
  AppName       = "My_new_pipeline"
  code_pipeline = local.code_pipeline

}
```

**SAMPlE local pipeline variable**

```
locals {

  /*
DECLARE enviornment variables.  Note each Action does not require environment variables
*/
  action_second_stage_variables = [
    {
      name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
    },
    {
      name  = "NamespaceVariable"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "some_value"
    },
  ]

  action_third_stage_variables = [
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_1"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VALUE1"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE 2"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VALUE2"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_3"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "VAUE3"
    },
    {
      name  = "PL_VARIABLE_4"
      type  = "PLAINTEXT"
      value = "#{BLD.NamespaceVariable}"
    },
  ]

  /*
BUILD YOUR STAGES
*/

  code_pipeline = {
    codepipeline-configs = {
      code_pipeline_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_name:role/role_name"
      artifact_store = {
        type            = "S3"
        artifact_bucket = "your-aws-bucket-name"
      }
      stages = {
        stage_1 = {
          name = "Download"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 1
              category         = "Source"
              name             = "First_Stage"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeCommit"
              version          = "1"
              output_artifacts = ["download_ouput"]
              configuration = {
                RepositoryName       = "Codecommit_target_repo"
                BranchName           = "main"
                PollForSourceChanges = true
                OutputArtifactFormat = "CODE_ZIP"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage_2 = {
          name = "Build"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 2
              category         = "Build"
              name             = "Second_Stage"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeBuild"
              version          = "1"
              namespace        = "BLD"
              input_artifacts  = ["Download_ouput"]
              output_artifacts = ["build_outputs"]
              configuration = {
                ProjectName          = "codebuild_project_name_for_second_stage"
                EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode(local.action_second_stage_variables)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage_3 = {
          name = "Validation"
          actions = {
            action_1 = {
              run_order        = 1
              name             = "Third_Stage"
              category         = "Build"
              owner            = "AWS"
              provider         = "CodeBuild"
              version          = "1"
              input_artifacts  = ["build_outputs"]
              output_artifacts = ["validation_outputs"]
              configuration = {
                ProjectName          = "codebuild_project_name_for_third_stage"
                EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode(local.action_third_stage_variables)
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The trick becomes building your code pipeline resource and its stages and actions at the local level. You take your local.tf and build out the pipeline variable there, you build out all your stages, actions, and EnvironmentVariables.   EnvironmentVariables are then passed and converted from JSON directly into the variable, which passes in as a single variable type.  A sample explaining this approach can be found within this [GitHub repository.](https://github.com/cwnit/toolkits/tree/master/collections/terraform/aws/aws-codepipeline/dynamic-pipeline)  I took the findings and consolidated them, and documented them so others could leverage this method.